# How can I store the recorded file inside the res folder?

Tags: android

I was trying to record a voice in my app and then store it inside the res folder. And I did more less the following:

```
private MediaRecorder recorder;


    static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "/MediaPlayer/res/raw/recordoutput.3gpp"; //MediaPlayer is the java class and raw is the folder that I would like to put my recorded voice in

private void beginRecording() throws Exception{
        killMediaRecorder();   //I implemented this function to kill the existing recorder
        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        if(outFile.exists())
        {
            outFile.delete();
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();

    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

But after i ran the emulator there is no file created inside the raw, can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** write to **res** folder, everything in the apk will be **read only**. You have to save your file in  your *internal storage* or to the *SD card*

Comment: Lol... this is exactly what I tried to say. I guess you didn't understand haha. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

No, applications cannot write to the internal storage of other applications.

You may either,

1. Write the file to your app's internal storage.
2. Write the file to the device's external storage.

Both are described in detail in the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Sorry, I should state that my apps is implemented inside the MediaPlayer project as well

Comment: I am only working with one application, dont quite understand what you mean by that

Comment: Is this the mediaplayer you are talking about? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: And you want to write the file to the `MediaPlayer`'s `res` directory?

Comment: MediaPlayer is my project name, Yes

Comment: OK... well that is what is confusing me. Your question sounds like you want to write to the `MediaPlayer` application's `res` directory... so this is not what you want?